# Android: Timer keep timer active when app in background - or AlarmManager?

Tags: android, timer, background

i use a timer in my app to start an async task (reading email) and put some status to the GUI - that works fine, as long as the app is not in background - then the timer seem to stop. Maybe it's normal.

Then i used the search function and read about the AlarmManager - but i want the timer only to run when my app is started.

How can i make sure the timer fires/works, no matter if the app/activity is in foreground / what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand well, you want a timer which runs only when the app is started, no matter whether it is in foreground or not. I see two options :

Set a timer in your activity : it can still live when activity is in background (onPaused or onStopped) but it can not interact with the GUI.  So, you could store data in some way, and use it when activity is resumed.

Other option is to use Android services, that can continue to live with your application and execute tasks even in the background. As previously, you can retrieve data from them when the activity is back.

You should read [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Indeed, alarm manager is designed for planning tasks even if your application is stopped.

Comment: Thank you - i did some tests and see that i'd rather use AlarmManager for some other reasons.

Comment: OK, no problem. By the way, you should consider closing this question if you have got your solution. And, if my answer helped you, maybe select it as preferred answer.